# Wikipedias proof of Little Picard Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

$\textbf{Theorem: Little Picard's Theorem:}$ Let $f$ be an entire function that omits $2$ values in its range, then $f$ is constant.

We begin by letting $a,b \in \Bbb{C}$ such that

$$f(z) \neq a, f(z) \neq b$$

for all $z \in \Bbb{C}$ then by considering

$$\frac{f(z)-a}{b-a}$$

we can, without any loss of generality assume $a=0,b=1$. As the range of $f$ omits $0$, there exists holomorphic entire function $g$ such that

$$f(z):=e^{2 \pi i g(z)}.$$

Then it says that $g$ omits integer values, is this because

$$\ln f(z) \neq 2 \pi i$$

for no such $z \in \Bbb{C}$? Then they go on to stating that by the quadratic formula there exists an entire function $h$ such that

$$g(z)=\cos (h(z))$$

My question is, how is the above by the quadratic formula? and does $g$ skip integer values due to the fact that for any $z \in \Bbb{C}$ we have

$$\ln f(z) \neq 2 \pi i$$

is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(z)\in\Bbb Z$, then $e^{2\pi ig(z)}=1$. In fact, $e^{z}=1$ if and only if $z=2\pi im$, for some $m\in\Bbb Z$. But $e^{2\pi ig(z)}=f(z)\ne1$.

Comment: How does it follow that $g(z)=\cos(h(z))$ for some entire function $h$, by the quadratic formula?

Comment: You have\begin{align}\cos(h(z))=g(z)&\iff e^{ih(z)}+e^{-ih(z)}=2g(z)\\&\iff\left(e^{ih(z)}\right)^2-2g(z)e^{ih(z)}+1=0.\end{align}

Comment: WOAH! wouldn't have came up with that on my own!